# Can't get usernames to show per object

Tags: javascript, json, instagram

**javascript**

```
var likesperimage = photo.likes.data;
console.log(likesperimage);
```

**displays**

[image: output]

When I try `var likesperimage = JSON.stringify(photo.likes.data);` inside my real coding it outputs the objects in full, but I only need usernames for each object per image. I have tried using jQuery each but this does not do what I really need.

Each grouped line which has Object in it is data from an image. so there are multiple usernames per image. And what Id like to do is show all the usernames that are tied in with the main object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why `jQuery.each` doesn't work for you? Try the following code:

```
var likesperimage = photo.likes.data;
var userList = [];
$.each(likesperimage, function(index, user) {
    userList.push(user.username);
});
console.log(userList);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(likesperimage, function(i, obj) {
    console.log(obj.username);
});
```

If you wanted a collection, you should be using `$.map` instead of `$.each`.

```
var names = $.map(likesperimage, function(obj, i) {
                                     return obj.username;
                                 });
```